# Binance get aggregated order book for larger tick size

Tags: binance, binance-api-client

I would like to take order book from binance API for larger tick size.

On web UI there is an option to change tick size to larger one and appropriate aggregated order book is shown on UI.

When I call  `api/v3/depth?symbol=BTCUSDT&limit=1000` to return order book, it returns only closest orders to current price and not for larger prices which could be seen when changed tick size to 100 on UI.

I have tried to changed limit from 10 to 5000, but it still return small prices from order book.

Does anyone knows how to get aggregated order book for larger tick sizes?